# MFSideMenu in secondary viewController

Tags: objective-c, navigationbar

I need to use MFSideMenu in all pages in my app. Now works in the first viewController, but when I select function in menu, the button is present in NavigationBar but it don't works...

How can I use this object?

I add in all my .h

```
- (IBAction)showRightMenuPressed:(id)sender;
```

and in all my .m

```
    - (IBAction)showRightMenuPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleRightSideMenuCompletion:nil];
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MFSideMenuContainerViewController** has properties like **leftMenuViewController**, **centerViewController** etc...  All you have to do is place a menuviewController as it's LeftMenuViewcontroller and a navigationController as it's centerViewController

```
  MenuViewController *VC = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
  ListViewController *ListVC = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
  TBNavigationController *NavigationVC = [[TBNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ListVC];

  /*
   Set the NavigationControllers as the ViewControllers of MFSideMenuContainer and make the MFSideMenuContainer as window's rootview.
   */

  MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                  containerWithCenterViewController:NavigationVC
                                                  leftMenuViewController:VC rightMenuViewController:nil];
  [[AppDelegate appDelegate].window setRootViewController:container];
```

Now keep adding as many VC's into the navigationController as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's my second app and the first I use this object... Where I need to add this code? in my appDelegate?

Comment: You can add it in appdelegate too with a small trick in the last line of that code.

Comment: in my appDelegate I have this code... 
 I see I need only last line of your code.. but with "[self.window setRootViewController:container] don't works...

Comment: self.window.rootViewController=container; in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions should work

Comment: It don't works! you said me I can add in appDelegate.... but... where do you add this code? in all my viewController in viewDidLoad?

Comment: you can add it in your loginView controller or app delegate . if that helped, vote me up

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnClkSide:(id)sender{
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
    //    SlideMenuOpem;
}
- (void)setupMenuBarButtonItems {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self rightMenuBarButtonItem];
    if(self.menuContainerViewController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateClosed &&
       ![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backBarButtonItem];
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
    }
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(rightSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's my second app and the first I use this object... Where I need to add this code?

Comment: use "btnClkSide" method on click of uibutton action